# How to get the comments of a file by using CSOM?

Tags: csom

I have an issue related to fetching the comments inside file/document by using CSOM.

This is an image of a comment that I want to get from file:

[image]

I used code like this but it doesn't work for me. It throws an exception:

[image]

```
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fileInformation = clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            clientContext.Load(fileInformation);
            await CustomExecuteQueryAsync();
            ClientResult<Stream> streamFileInformation = fileInformation.OpenBinaryStream();
            await CustomExecuteQueryAsync();

            ListItem item = fileInformation.ListItemAllFields;
            clientContext.Load(item);
            await CustomExecuteQueryAsync();

            string comments = item["Comments"].ToString();
```